# Select every 3rd and 4th item from the list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am wanting to select every 3rd and 4th list item from a list, I tried the following but it did not seem to work reliably.

```
.ty-subcategories__item:nth-child(2n+1) .ty-btn,
.ty-subcategories__item:nth-child(3n+1) .ty-btn,
```

Must be doing it wrong, anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select 3rd and 4th item from groups of 4 then you need to do this:

```css
li:nth-child(4n+3),
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The +1 in your styles is not necessary. `3n` and `4n` work just fine:

```css
ul li:nth-child(3n) {background:red}
ul li:nth-child(4n) {background:blue}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
</ul>
```

Note, this means every 3rd `li` is red and every 4th `li` is blue. If they both fall on the same `li`, it will be blue since it is defined latest.

If this is not your desired outcome, please explain.

Comment: That is what i want but its not working as expected when i integrate for some reason. let me do a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/71e5189r/1/ - your need ot make full width as possible to not be in mobile version but your see what i mean.

Comment: That is a ton of HTML code to look through. Additionally, I don't understand where the problem lies. To make it easier to help, edit your question with the related HTML code and CSS, then maybe even provide a screenshot of the problem that is happening.

Comment: Dont worry matey, i have sorted it. Done a different way - your answer is correct though :)